# Cannot add borders to the sections CSS

Tags: html, css, border, sections

I want to add borders to each of the sections in the table (Which means two borders separating the two sections. Assuming this table has headers already):

```
<table>
    <section class="physicists">

        <tr class="Richard-Feynman">
            <td>Richard Feynman</td>
            <td>Image1</td>
            <td>Descrption1</td>            
        </tr>

        <tr class="Albert-Einstein">
            <td>Albert Einstein</td>
            <td>Image2</td>
            <td>Descrption2</td>            
        </tr>

    </section>

    <section class="martial-artists">

        <tr class="Bruce-Lee">
            <td>Bruce Lee</td>
            <td>Image3</td>
            <td>Descrption3</td>            
        </tr>

        <tr class="Chunk-Norris">
            <td>Chunk Norris</td>
            <td>Image4</td>
            <td>Descrption4</td>            
        </tr>

    </section>
</table>
```

I was attempting with the following CSS code, but the border-bottom does not appear

```
section[class="physicists"] {

    border-top: solid 3px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px;
    border-color: red;

}
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: `section .physicists { }`

Comment: You can't have a `<section>` element in a table. It's invalid HTML, and most browsers will attempt to fix the error by changing your HTML

Comment: @clxrity It's worth putting code through a validator - it will pick up errors like mal-formed HTML which is a problem we have here.

Comment: If you need to group multiple table rows in one table, you could use multiple `<tbody />` elements that have `<tr />` elements as its children. It is outlined in [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1). You can do something like [this code example](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/grouping-tr-table-rows/6966/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `<tbody>` instead of `<section>`

As others noted in the comments, `<table>` cannot contain `<section>` as its valid child element. Instead, `<tbody>` element is meant for this exact purpose.

##### 1. An example with `<th>` as section heading

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
tbody > tr > th {
  background: #c6c8d2;
}

tbody {
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="physicists">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Physicists</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Richard-Feynman">
      <td>Richard Feynman</td>
      <td>Image1</td>
      <td>Descrption1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Albert-Einstein">
      <td>Albert Einstein</td>
      <td>Image2</td>
      <td>Descrption2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="martial-artists">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Martial Artists</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Bruce-Lee">
      <td>Bruce Lee</td>
      <td>Image3</td>
      <td>Descrption3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Chunk-Norris">
      <td>Chunk Norris</td>
      <td>Image4</td>
      <td>Descrption4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

##### 2. An example without section heading

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

tbody {
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="physicists">
    <tr class="Richard-Feynman">
      <td>Richard Feynman</td>
      <td>Image1</td>
      <td>Descrption1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Albert-Einstein">
      <td>Albert Einstein</td>
      <td>Image2</td>
      <td>Descrption2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="martial-artists">
    <tr class="Bruce-Lee">
      <td>Bruce Lee</td>
      <td>Image3</td>
      <td>Descrption3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Chunk-Norris">
      <td>Chunk Norris</td>
      <td>Image4</td>
      <td>Descrption4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Apply `border-collapse: collapse;` to the parent table

> When cells are separated, the distance between cells is defined by the `border-spacing` property.

`border-collapse` determines how the table cells would handle their borders. If not set, it's `separate` by default. For details, see [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse).

Answer (score 1):

First bug:
At first, `<section>` element can't be used that way.
The `table` can be embedded in the `section` but not the other way around.

Split it to two tables like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Eckert Művek Galéria</title>    
</head>
<body>
  <table class="physicists my-frame">
    <tr class="Richard-Feynman">
      <td>Richard Feynman</td>
      <td>Image1</td>
      <td>Descrption1</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr class="Albert-Einstein">
      <td>Albert Einstein</td>
      <td>Image2</td>
      <td>Descrption2</td>            
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="martial-artists my-frame">
    <tr class="Bruce-Lee">
      <td>Bruce Lee</td>
      <td>Image3</td>
      <td>Descrption3</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr class="Chunk-Norris">
      <td>Chunk Norris</td>
      <td>Image4</td>
      <td>Descrption4</td>            
    </tr>
  </table>

  <style>
    .my-frame {
      border-top: solid 3px;
      border-bottom: solid 3px;
      border-color: red;
      width:100%;
      margin-top:5px;
    }
        
    .my-frame td{
      width:33%;
    }
  </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Second info:
This is not the best way to write selectors:

```
section[class="physicists"]{ /* ... */ }
```

Better is:

```
section.physicists{ /* ... */ }
```